Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu kali-rolling Release 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
i typed:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio

it response:
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/ kali-rolling main'
Description:
Latest stable release of OBS Studio
More info: https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-kali-rolling.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-kali-rolling.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio.gpg with fingerprint BC7345F522079769F5BBE987EFC71127F425E228
Hit:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                     
Hit:2 https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster InRelease                                                
Hit:3 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                               
Ign:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu kali-rolling InRelease
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu kali-rolling Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

i tried installing it using
sudo apt install obs-studio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package obs-studio


Don't forget PPAs are 3rd party repositories, so all security checks are on you to perform (ie. did you check https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio)..   I suggest you check https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ as don't forget Kali Linux has many standard Debian security features disabled as it makes Pen testing easier.. after all Pen testing is intended to be used to protect other systems and not yourself (after all you're using a disposable live machine with nothing of value)
